# Duda sobre relación entre Votos - Reputación

Tags: discusión

Tengo la siguiente curiosidad/duda:
Cuando un usuario obtiene una cierta cantidad de reputación por haber obtenido un voto a favor a su pregunta y luego quien votó se arrepiente y retira su voto, ¿el usuario pierde los puntos de reputación ganados por ese voto? o se mantienen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe una ventana de tiempo para retirar el voto, ya sea a favor o en contra, de 15 minutos (por revisar). Si se retira un voto a favor, el sistema va a recalcular la reputación del usuario que ahora tiene un voto menos en su publicación, lo que significa en una disminución de reputación, se reduce en 5 si se removió el voto a una pregunta y en 10 si se removió el voto a una respuesta.

Comment: Ya, es decir que la reputación baja si se retira el voto a favor. Gracias